# Chromecast streaming issue (DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found)

Tags: casting, chromecast

I am trying to cast to this cast receiver ID: CB2BD90D

This is a custom styled receiver.

The video URL to cast:

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ht-brightcove/FinAAC_V1/playlist.m3u8

This is the error that I get when debug using chrome remote debug tool:

> [cast.player.api.Player] error      media_player.js:61
>
> [cast.player.api.Host] error:
> cast.player.api.ErrorCode.PLAYBACK/104    media_player.js:61
>
> [cast.player.api.Player] unload player.html:1 Uncaught (in promise)
>
> DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

It was playing perfectly before a month. Now It is throwing this error.

Please Help me guys.

Comment: If you are using `HTMLMediaElement.play()`, here is the explanation [why it returns a promise](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise?hl=en): A `play()` call on an a `<video>` or `<audio>` element now returns a [Promise](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises). If playback succeeds, the Promise is fulfilled, and if playback fails, the Promise is rejected along with an error message explaining the failure. To understand further, [see the live example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/play-return-promise/).

Comment: It seems, the video is in 5.1 audio codec and it caused the issue. Previously it was working well with the file. Solved the issue by changing audio codec for every videos.